# Is saying "you look worn out" rude?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I've heard "you look tired" is sometimes rude. Then, can I say "you look worn out" instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meanings and uses of "You look tired" and "You look worn out" are sufficiently similar that when one is thought rude, the other will probably also be thought rude.

Whether either will be thought rude depends on the relationship between speaker and listener, on the particular community to which speaker and listener belong, on the context, and on the tone of voice used.

Persons who are in a close and friendly relationship, such as (some) family members and close friends, may have such comments taken as sincere and well-meant inquires about the state f a person's health. When the parties are not so close, such an inquiry may seem intrusive or rude, or as a negative comment on a person's appearance.

In some communities such inquiries are common, and are generally taken as an honest concern. In other communities, such inquiries are rare, and more apt to be taken negatively.

Context, in this case the general subject and tone of previous conversation, may greatly affect how such a comment is taken. And finally, but perhaps most important, the tone of voice used may make  a huge difference in how such a comment is received.

Comment: In Britain, saying 'you look shagged out' would be OK to a drinking buddy, but rude to your grandmother.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually expect "You look tired" to be rude in fewer situations. The two can be nearly synonymous but "You look worn out" can also mean something like "having been treated poorly by life", not just not being rested at the moment. And that second meaning I could easily expect to be taken as rude in plenty of circumstances.